# How do I add a light fixture to an existing 3 way circuit when the existing one is powered directly?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, light-fixture

I am trying to add another light fixture to an existing 3 way circuit. The power source feeds to the ceiling light fixture which is connected to the first three way switch using a 2 wire cable.

That cable in turn connects to the second 3 way switch. Here is a schematic, but without the additional fixtures wired from the light:3

Current wiring:

[image: Current wiring]

I tried to wire the second light off of the first 3 way switch thinking it had the power source, but when I turned on the breaker, both lights were dim. I am thinking that the second light is in series with the first light, which obviously is not what I want.

Is there a way to fix this without the running cable from the first light fixture to the second one. It is a royal pain to fish wire across the ceiling. My hunch is that it can't be done, but It doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: I'm confused... Where are you trying to connect the new fixture?  Why can't you wire it exactly as the image?

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to avoid fishing wire across the joists. The current wiring from the second light back to the box is a straight shot and already installed, albeit doesn't quite function.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see it being able to be done. Theres just not enough wires. Basically whats missing is after you get your switched power to your light you need a path back to the main (source) neutral. Or any neutral really. You do have white wires in the 3 way switch boxed but they are acting as travellers and not neutrals. Sorry for your bum luck. I hate being short wires!
If you could pull a 3 wire to replace the 2 wire between the source power light fixture and the 3 way switch box on the right, than you could then feed a light fixture off that 3 way. I am not sure if thats easier for you...